# вывести сообщение если текст в адресной строке содержит определенные символы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

помогите написать простой скрипт, не знаю возможно ли это с помощью javascript.

Если текст в адресной содержит `?field_number_value` и на странице есть блок `class="block"`, то вывести alert "скрипт работает".

Если насчет второй части я могу еще проверить, то как проверить адресную строку я ума не приложу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[console.log(window.location);](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/location)

Конкретно `?field_number_value`:

```
console.log(location.search)
```

Условие:

```
if(location.search.indexOf('?field_number_value')!=-1)
```

Comment: знал бы я что это такое и как оно связано с моей строчкой

Comment: нажмите кнопку f12 в браузере. там консоль - очень полезная вещь. Ваша строчка ?field_number_value лежит в глобальном объекте location в атрибуте search, там вы можете его проверять на наличие нужного вам слова

Comment: мне нужно чтобы скрипт проверял адресную строку на наличие слова и если слово есть то выводить alert "скрипт работает"

Comment: Добавил условие в ответ

Comment: Пользуйтесь для отладки консолью, а не алертами. Она в каждом браузере есть, и очень помогает.

Answer (score 1):

Проверил, в FF работает:

```
    if( ~window.location.search.indexOf('field_number_value')  
        &&  document.getElementsByClassName('block').length) {
        alert("Works!");
    } else {
        alert("Doesn't work");
    }
```

Comment: Зачем использовать `!!` в `if`? Ему же не важно, bool там или нет. И для `&&` тоже неважно.

Comment: @Qwertiy действительно. Обновил.

Answer (score 0):

Подойдет?

```
if (window.location.pathname.indexOf('field_number_value')!=-1 && $('.block').length) {
    alert('скрипт работает');
}
```

Comment: для `.indexOf()`, помните, этот красивый хак есть: `!!~` вместо `!=-1`? Байт сэкономленный – байт заработанный! )

Comment: написал уже несколько скриптов они все срабатывают а вот те которые нужно чтобы взаимодействовали с адресной строкой - нет, А это  жесткое условие #indexOf('field_number_value')#?? потому что как вы понимаете в адаресной строке кроме этого еще и адрес сайта и еще куча других параметров написаны

Comment: В `window.location.pathname` нет параметров GET-запроса. Они есть в `href` и `search`.